# How to only validate a form when submitting it?

Tags: angular, forms

I'm working with this simple **Reactive form** and I'm trying to validate it only when clicking on **"Send Data"** button. Can someone tell me what I'm missing please? Thanks a lot in advance!

Here's my code: [**LIVE DEMO**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-reactive-form-amssox?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)

```
 get username(){
   return this.registrationFormGroup.get('username');
 }

 get userlastname(){
  return this.registrationFormGroup.get('userlastname');
 }

 get userage(){
  return this.registrationFormGroup.get('userage');
 }

 onSubmit(){
   if(this.registrationFormGroup.valid){
    console.log('Sending data...');
    console.log(this.registrationFormGroup.value);
   }
 }
```

Comment: What are you trying to avoid that is leading you to only want validation on submission?

Comment: I have the validation on each field already, but I don't want to validate the form until the user clicks on the submit button.

Comment: Doesn’t that happen automatically if you’re using ngSubmit?

Comment: @BenSteward Yes, you are right. However, the issue is if the user focuses on field 1, then Tabs to the second field, the validation executes right away (I don't want that). I only want to show error messages when clicking on the submit button. Hope that make sense

Comment: I’ve seen `errorStateMatcher`s in the Material library, I don’t know if you could use something like that to short circuit the normal behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `field.touched` and you can use the condition if the form is submitted.

With `#form="ngForm"` you can use `form.submitted` condition.

```
<form #form="ngForm" [formGroup]="registrationFormGroup" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <input [class.is-invalid]="form.submitted && username.invalid" type="text" formControlName="username"><br/>
    <small *ngIf="form.submitted && username.invalid && username.errors.required" style="color:red;">Name is required</small>

    //Rest of your form... 
</form>
```

You can see in this [DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-reactive-form-wpqrks?file=app/app.component.html)

Comment: Can you provide a stackbliz or a live demo? Thanks